# 'glib.h' file not found on Max OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, emacs, makefile, glib

I'm trying to compile [msg2pdf](https://github.com/djcb/mu/tree/master/toys/msg2pdf) which is a tool to convert messages in mu4e (mu for Emacs) to pdf.
I'm receiving the following error :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in .
  CC       msg2pdf.o
In file included from msg2pdf.c:20:
In file included from ../../lib/mu-msg.h:24:
../../lib/mu-flags.h:24:10: fatal error: 'glib.h' file not found
#include <glib.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [msg2pdf.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Oddly, I checked the Makefile and GLIB_CFLAGS seem to be pointing on the right folder (where brew installed it). 
In fact, `glib.h` is located in `/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.40.0_1/include/glib-2.0`.

```
GLIB_CFLAGS = -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.40.0_1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.40.0_1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include 
GLIB_LIBS = -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.40.0_1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

How can I succeed compiling the file? Is there any command line "hack" I can use while calling 
make?

**Edit**
Here are the files in the directory
https://github.com/flexdec/temp

**Edit 2**
This is the output when using make V=1

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in .
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..  -I../../lib   -DICONDIR='""'  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wdeclaration-after-statement -g -O2 -MT msg2pdf.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/msg2pdf.Tpo -c -o msg2pdf.o msg2pdf.c
In file included from msg2pdf.c:20:
In file included from ../../lib/mu-msg.h:24:
../../lib/mu-flags.h:24:10: fatal error: 'glib.h' file not found
#include <glib.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [msg2pdf.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Edit 3**
The new error I get using `make V=1` now that GLIB_CFLAGS issue is fixed

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in .
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..  -I../../lib   -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.40.0_1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.40.0_1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include  -DICONDIR='""'  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wdeclaration-after-statement -g -O2 -MT msg2pdf.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/msg2pdf.Tpo -c -o msg2pdf.o msg2pdf.c
msg2pdf.c:24:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [msg2pdf.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You didn't show what the command to the C compiler looks like (try `make V=1` instead of just `make`).  Maybe the GLIB_CFLAGS aren't actually being passed to the CC...?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm quite a beginner in the compiling field. I get the same error with `make V=1`. I edited the post with a link to the files in the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make V=1` instead of `make` will tell you what the C compiler command looks like (instead of just "CC       msg2pdf.o")—check that and make sure it includes the flags you need.

Based on a quick look at your Makefile.am, you are including $(GTK_CFLAGS) and $(WEBKIT_CFLAGS) in your AM_CPPFLAGS but not $(GLIB_CFLAGS).

Comment: Thanks I edited my message with the make V=1 output. But to be honest, this is chinese to me. Normally I'm used to do ./configure make install but thats pretty much it, I never even touched a makefile...

Comment: The relevant flags definitely didn't make it into the command line.  Did you add $(GLIB_CFLAGS) to AM_CPPFLAGS and AM_CFLAGS?

Comment: haha it passed! But now I get a new error. 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found. I downloaded it via brew too but it doesnt seem to be recognized

Comment: If you look at the Makefile, GTK_CFLAGS, GTK_LIBS, WEBKIT_CFLAGS, and WEBKIT_LIBS are empty.  You're probably missing the pkg-config check and AC_SUBST in your configure.ac

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated pkg-config path and I relaunched configure and now I have  'webkit/webkitwebview.h' file not found haha, I'll get trough it!

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the pkg-config check and AC_SUBST for webkitgtk-3.0 (or webkit2gtk-3.0).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run ./configure in mu's top-level directory on the machine where you want to compile it. configure will tell you about any missing dependencies. Optional components (such as msg2pdf) are skipped if their dependencies are not there.

Then, after configure succeeds, do a 'make'.

In any case, if configure has run successfully, the top-level 'make' should succeed as well (that's why we have configure!), otherwise please file a bug.